Extract Keywords from Text Vector -- one set of keyworks for each element
Please consider the reprex at the end of the post.
It works along the lines of
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udpipe/vignettes/udpipe-usecase-postagging-lemmatisation.html
It extracts a set of keywords from a text vector "texts", but I would like to have
4 sets of keywords,i.e. one set of keywords for each for each element of "texts".
I added another section to the reprex where I try using map after splitting the initial dataset and converting it to a list. I do not get any error messages, but it clearly does not work.
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Many thanks!
# Load required libraries
library(udpipe)
library(tidyverse)
library(lattice)

## see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udpipe/vignettes/udpipe-usecase-postagging-lemmatisation.html

# Download and load the model
model <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
#> Downloading udpipe model from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jwijffels/udpipe.models.ud.2.5/master/inst/udpipe-ud-2.5-191206/english-ewt-ud-2.5-191206.udpipe to /home/lorenzo/mega_pcloud/work/web-intelligence/english-ewt-ud-2.5-191206.udpipe
#>  - This model has been trained on version 2.5 of data from https://universaldependencies.org
#>  - The model is distributed under the CC-BY-SA-NC license: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0
#>  - Visit https://github.com/jwijffels/udpipe.models.ud.2.5 for model license details.
#>  - For a list of all models and their licenses (most models you can download with this package have either a CC-BY-SA or a CC-BY-SA-NC license) read the documentation at ?udpipe_download_model. For building your own models: visit the documentation by typing vignette('udpipe-train', package = 'udpipe')
#> Downloading finished, model stored at '/home/lorenzo/mega_pcloud/work/web-intelligence/english-ewt-ud-2.5-191206.udpipe'
ud_model <- udpipe_load_model(model$file_model)

# Sample text vector with longer text elements
texts <- c(
  "The first document contains a lot of information about natural language processing. It discusses various methods such as tokenization, stemming, and lemmatization. Additionally, it covers advanced topics like named entity recognition and sentiment analysis. The document emphasizes the importance of understanding linguistic structures and nuances. It also touches upon the challenges and limitations of current NLP technologies.",
  "In the second document, we delve deeper into machine learning techniques applied to text data. This includes algorithms like support vector machines, naive Bayes, and deep learning models. The document also explains feature extraction and vectorization techniques. Furthermore, it provides a comprehensive overview of hyperparameter tuning and model evaluation metrics. The goal is to highlight the critical aspects of building robust and efficient text classifiers.",
  "The third document focuses on practical applications of text mining. It provides examples of text classification, clustering, and topic modeling. Moreover, it highlights the importance of preprocessing steps like removing stopwords and normalizing text. The document also explores various use cases in different industries, demonstrating the versatility of text mining techniques. Additionally, it discusses future trends and emerging technologies in the field.",
  "Finally, the fourth document reviews different tools and libraries available for text analysis. It mentions popular libraries such as NLTK, spaCy, and gensim. The document also includes comparisons between these tools in terms of performance and ease of use. It aims to guide readers in selecting the most appropriate tools for their specific needs. Additionally, it provides best practices for integrating these tools into existing workflows and systems."
)

# Create a data frame
text_df <- tibble(doc_id = 1:length(texts), text = texts)

# Annotate the texts
 x <- udpipe_annotate(ud_model, x = text_df$text) |>
    as_tibble()

 x
#> # A tibble: 288 × 14
#>    doc_id paragraph_id sentence_id sentence     token_id token lemma upos  xpos 
#>    <chr>         <int>       <int> <chr>        <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 doc1              1           1 The first d… 1        The   the   DET   DT   
#>  2 doc1              1           1 The first d… 2        first first ADJ   JJ   
#>  3 doc1              1           1 The first d… 3        docu… docu… NOUN  NN   
#>  4 doc1              1           1 The first d… 4        cont… cont… VERB  VBZ  
#>  5 doc1              1           1 The first d… 5        a     a     DET   DT   
#>  6 doc1              1           1 The first d… 6        lot   lot   NOUN  NN   
#>  7 doc1              1           1 The first d… 7        of    of    ADP   IN   
#>  8 doc1              1           1 The first d… 8        info… info… NOUN  NN   
#>  9 doc1              1           1 The first d… 9        about about ADP   IN   
#> 10 doc1              1           1 The first d… 10       natu… natu… ADJ   JJ   
#> # ℹ 278 more rows
#> # ℹ 5 more variables: feats <chr>, head_token_id <chr>, dep_rel <chr>,
#> #   deps <chr>, misc <chr>

stats <- keywords_rake(x = x, term = "lemma", group = "doc_id", 
                       relevant = x$upos %in% c("NOUN", "ADJ"))

stats$key <- factor(stats$keyword, levels = rev(stats$keyword))

barchart(key ~ rake, data = stats 
       , col = "cadetblue", 
         main = "Keywords identified by RAKE", 
         xlab = "Rake")



################################################################


text_df_split <- text_df |>
    group_by(doc_id) |>
    group_split()



 x_split <- map(text_df_split, \(x) udpipe_annotate(ud_model, x$text) |> as_tibble() )

## let us see what x looks like

x |> glimpse()
#> Rows: 288
#> Columns: 14
#> $ doc_id        <chr> "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", …
#> $ paragraph_id  <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,…
#> $ sentence_id   <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,…
#> $ sentence      <chr> "The first document contains a lot of information about …
#> $ token_id      <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11",…
#> $ token         <chr> "The", "first", "document", "contains", "a", "lot", "of"…
#> $ lemma         <chr> "the", "first", "document", "contain", "a", "lot", "of",…
#> $ upos          <chr> "DET", "ADJ", "NOUN", "VERB", "DET", "NOUN", "ADP", "NOU…
#> $ xpos          <chr> "DT", "JJ", "NN", "VBZ", "DT", "NN", "IN", "NN", "IN", "…
#> $ feats         <chr> "Definite=Def|PronType=Art", "Degree=Pos|NumType=Ord", "…
#> $ head_token_id <chr> "3", "3", "4", "0", "6", "4", "8", "6", "12", "12", "12"…
#> $ dep_rel       <chr> "det", "amod", "nsubj", "root", "det", "obj", "case", "n…
#> $ deps          <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ misc          <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "SpaceAfter=…

## and what my second element in the list looks like

x_split[[2]] |> glimpse()
#> Rows: 74
#> Columns: 14
#> $ doc_id        <chr> "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", …
#> $ paragraph_id  <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,…
#> $ sentence_id   <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,…
#> $ sentence      <chr> "In the second document, we delve deeper into machine le…
#> $ token_id      <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11",…
#> $ token         <chr> "In", "the", "second", "document", ",", "we", "delve", "…
#> $ lemma         <chr> "in", "the", "second", "document", ",", "we", "delve", "…
#> $ upos          <chr> "ADP", "DET", "ADJ", "NOUN", "PUNCT", "PRON", "VERB", "A…
#> $ xpos          <chr> "IN", "DT", "JJ", "NN", ",", "PRP", "VBP", "RB", "IN", "…
#> $ feats         <chr> NA, "Definite=Def|PronType=Art", "Degree=Pos|NumType=Ord…
#> $ head_token_id <chr> "4", "4", "4", "7", "7", "7", "0", "7", "12", "11", "12"…
#> $ dep_rel       <chr> "case", "det", "amod", "obl", "punct", "nsubj", "root", …
#> $ deps          <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ misc          <chr> NA, NA, NA, "SpaceAfter=No", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,…

## it looks like they have the same structure,
## but when I try using keywords_rake on it


stats_split_2 <- keywords_rake(x = x_split[[2]], term = "lemma", group = "doc_id", 
                       relevant = x_split[[2]]$upos %in% c("NOUN", "ADJ"))


## I do not get an error, but see what happens

stats_split_2|>glimpse()
#> Rows: 0
#> Columns: 4
#> $ keyword <chr> 
#> $ ngram   <int> 
#> $ freq    <int> 
#> $ rake    <dbl>

Created on 2024-06-19 with reprex v2.1.0

What is max(x$paragraph_id)?

it is 1. No idea of what that means and how to modify it if necessary,

I think the issue was that, given that the text is short, I have to allow keywords to appear only once (n_min=1).
The example in the reprex works.
# Load required libraries
library(udpipe)
library(tidyverse)
library(lattice)

## see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udpipe/vignettes/udpipe-usecase-postagging-lemmatisation.html

# Download and load the model
model <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
#> Downloading udpipe model from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jwijffels/udpipe.models.ud.2.5/master/inst/udpipe-ud-2.5-191206/english-ewt-ud-2.5-191206.udpipe to /home/lorenzo/mega_pcloud/work/web-intelligence/english-ewt-ud-2.5-191206.udpipe
#>  - This model has been trained on version 2.5 of data from https://universaldependencies.org
#>  - The model is distributed under the CC-BY-SA-NC license: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0
#>  - Visit https://github.com/jwijffels/udpipe.models.ud.2.5 for model license details.
#>  - For a list of all models and their licenses (most models you can download with this package have either a CC-BY-SA or a CC-BY-SA-NC license) read the documentation at ?udpipe_download_model. For building your own models: visit the documentation by typing vignette('udpipe-train', package = 'udpipe')
#> Downloading finished, model stored at '/home/lorenzo/mega_pcloud/work/web-intelligence/english-ewt-ud-2.5-191206.udpipe'
ud_model <- udpipe_load_model(model$file_model)

# Sample text vector with longer text elements
texts <- c(
  "The first document contains a lot of information about natural language processing. It discusses various methods such as tokenization, stemming, and lemmatization. Additionally, it covers advanced topics like named entity recognition and sentiment analysis. The document emphasizes the importance of understanding linguistic structures and nuances. It also touches upon the challenges and limitations of current NLP technologies.",
  "In the second document, we delve deeper into machine learning techniques applied to text data. This includes algorithms like support vector machines, naive Bayes, and deep learning models. The document also explains feature extraction and vectorization techniques. Furthermore, it provides a comprehensive overview of hyperparameter tuning and model evaluation metrics. The goal is to highlight the critical aspects of building robust and efficient text classifiers.",
  "The third document focuses on practical applications of text mining. It provides examples of text classification, clustering, and topic modeling. Moreover, it highlights the importance of preprocessing steps like removing stopwords and normalizing text. The document also explores various use cases in different industries, demonstrating the versatility of text mining techniques. Additionally, it discusses future trends and emerging technologies in the field.",
  "Finally, the fourth document reviews different tools and libraries available for text analysis. It mentions popular libraries such as NLTK, spaCy, and gensim. The document also includes comparisons between these tools in terms of performance and ease of use. It aims to guide readers in selecting the most appropriate tools for their specific needs. Additionally, it provides best practices for integrating these tools into existing workflows and systems."
)

# Create a data frame
text_df <- tibble(doc_id = 1:length(texts), text = texts)

# Annotate the texts
 x <- udpipe_annotate(ud_model, x = text_df$text) |>
    as_tibble()

 x
#> # A tibble: 288 × 14
#>    doc_id paragraph_id sentence_id sentence     token_id token lemma upos  xpos 
#>    <chr>         <int>       <int> <chr>        <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 doc1              1           1 The first d… 1        The   the   DET   DT   
#>  2 doc1              1           1 The first d… 2        first first ADJ   JJ   
#>  3 doc1              1           1 The first d… 3        docu… docu… NOUN  NN   
#>  4 doc1              1           1 The first d… 4        cont… cont… VERB  VBZ  
#>  5 doc1              1           1 The first d… 5        a     a     DET   DT   
#>  6 doc1              1           1 The first d… 6        lot   lot   NOUN  NN   
#>  7 doc1              1           1 The first d… 7        of    of    ADP   IN   
#>  8 doc1              1           1 The first d… 8        info… info… NOUN  NN   
#>  9 doc1              1           1 The first d… 9        about about ADP   IN   
#> 10 doc1              1           1 The first d… 10       natu… natu… ADJ   JJ   
#> # ℹ 278 more rows
#> # ℹ 5 more variables: feats <chr>, head_token_id <chr>, dep_rel <chr>,
#> #   deps <chr>, misc <chr>

stats <- keywords_rake(x = x, term = "lemma", group = "doc_id", 
                       relevant = x$upos %in% c("NOUN", "ADJ"))

stats$key <- factor(stats$keyword, levels = rev(stats$keyword))

barchart(key ~ rake, data = stats 
       , col = "cadetblue", 
         main = "Keywords identified by RAKE", 
         xlab = "Rake")



################################################################


text_df_split <- text_df |>
    group_by(doc_id) |>
    group_split()



 x_split <- map(text_df_split, \(x) udpipe_annotate(ud_model, x$text) |> as_tibble() )

## let us see what x looks like

x |> glimpse()
#> Rows: 288
#> Columns: 14
#> $ doc_id        <chr> "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", …
#> $ paragraph_id  <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,…
#> $ sentence_id   <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,…
#> $ sentence      <chr> "The first document contains a lot of information about …
#> $ token_id      <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11",…
#> $ token         <chr> "The", "first", "document", "contains", "a", "lot", "of"…
#> $ lemma         <chr> "the", "first", "document", "contain", "a", "lot", "of",…
#> $ upos          <chr> "DET", "ADJ", "NOUN", "VERB", "DET", "NOUN", "ADP", "NOU…
#> $ xpos          <chr> "DT", "JJ", "NN", "VBZ", "DT", "NN", "IN", "NN", "IN", "…
#> $ feats         <chr> "Definite=Def|PronType=Art", "Degree=Pos|NumType=Ord", "…
#> $ head_token_id <chr> "3", "3", "4", "0", "6", "4", "8", "6", "12", "12", "12"…
#> $ dep_rel       <chr> "det", "amod", "nsubj", "root", "det", "obj", "case", "n…
#> $ deps          <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ misc          <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "SpaceAfter=…

## and what my second element in the list looks like

x_split[[2]] |> glimpse()
#> Rows: 74
#> Columns: 14
#> $ doc_id        <chr> "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", "doc1", …
#> $ paragraph_id  <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,…
#> $ sentence_id   <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,…
#> $ sentence      <chr> "In the second document, we delve deeper into machine le…
#> $ token_id      <chr> "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11",…
#> $ token         <chr> "In", "the", "second", "document", ",", "we", "delve", "…
#> $ lemma         <chr> "in", "the", "second", "document", ",", "we", "delve", "…
#> $ upos          <chr> "ADP", "DET", "ADJ", "NOUN", "PUNCT", "PRON", "VERB", "A…
#> $ xpos          <chr> "IN", "DT", "JJ", "NN", ",", "PRP", "VBP", "RB", "IN", "…
#> $ feats         <chr> NA, "Definite=Def|PronType=Art", "Degree=Pos|NumType=Ord…
#> $ head_token_id <chr> "4", "4", "4", "7", "7", "7", "0", "7", "12", "11", "12"…
#> $ dep_rel       <chr> "case", "det", "amod", "obl", "punct", "nsubj", "root", …
#> $ deps          <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ misc          <chr> NA, NA, NA, "SpaceAfter=No", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,…

## it looks like they have the same structure,
## but when I try using keywords_rake on it

## the text is short, so I need to set n_min=1 in the rake algorithm

stats_split_2 <- keywords_rake(x = x_split[[2]], term = "lemma", group = "doc_id", 
                               relevant = x_split[[2]]$upos %in% c("NOUN", "ADJ"),
                               n_min=1)




stats_split_2|>glimpse()
#> Rows: 14
#> Columns: 4
#> $ keyword <chr> "text data", "naive Baye", "critical aspect", "building robust…
#> $ ngram   <int> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
#> $ freq    <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
#> $ rake    <dbl> 2.5, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.5, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.…


stats_split_all <- map(x_split, \(x)  keywords_rake(x = x, term = "lemma",
                                                    group = "doc_id", 
                               relevant = x$upos %in% c("NOUN", "ADJ"),
                               n_min=1)
   )


stats_split_all |> glimpse()
#> List of 4
#>  $ :'data.frame':    13 obs. of  4 variables:
#>   ..$ keyword: chr [1:13] "advanced topics" "sentiment analysis" "entity recognition" "first document" ...
#>   ..$ ngram  : int [1:13] 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>   ..$ freq   : int [1:13] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>   ..$ rake   : num [1:13] 2 2 2 1.5 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    14 obs. of  4 variables:
#>   ..$ keyword: chr [1:14] "text data" "naive Baye" "critical aspect" "building robust" ...
#>   ..$ ngram  : int [1:14] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
#>   ..$ freq   : int [1:14] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>   ..$ rake   : num [1:14] 2.5 2 2 2 2 2 2 1.5 1.5 1 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    17 obs. of  4 variables:
#>   ..$ keyword: chr [1:17] "text mining" "text classification" "normalize text" "practical application" ...
#>   ..$ ngram  : int [1:17] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
#>   ..$ freq   : int [1:17] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>   ..$ rake   : num [1:17] 2.75 2.25 2.25 2 2 2 2 1.5 0.5 0 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    16 obs. of  4 variables:
#>   ..$ keyword: chr [1:16] "library available" "appropriate tool" "text analysis" "best practices" ...
#>   ..$ ngram  : int [1:16] 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
#>   ..$ freq   : int [1:16] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
#>   ..$ rake   : num [1:16] 2.5 2.25 2 2 2 2 1.25 0 0 0 ...

Created on 2024-06-19 with reprex v2.1.0
